# Help finding Bayesian model with multi-modal posterior

Tags: bayesian, modeling, markov-chain-montecarlo, generative-models, normalizing-flow

**Background:**

There is a paper ([link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.12603)) that concerns combining MCMC methods with a normalizing flow (a type of generative model). The basic idea is that the normalizing flow helps propose samples, which are then either accepted or rejected. The method is supposed to help speed convergence to the target distribution when the target is "complex", e.g., multimodal.

I have been given a job to try to extend the methods in the paper to consider multiple normalizing flows. Unfortunately, I have no background in this area, or with MCMC at all.

**Need for example:**

I am supposed to find a real example from a Bayesian model to test my methods on. Because I have no experience in this area, I don't precisely know what I'm looking for.

**I am requesting help finding something along these lines:**

- A Bayesian model of some real-life situation (from a textbook or paper) that I can describe
- Resulting in a formula for the posterior, up to a proportionality constant
- Posterior is multi-modal
- Hopefully the posterior is maybe 2-dimensional, so I can visualize it
- Ideally with some knowledge of where the modes of the posterior are, because that is important for the methods to work

Basically, I'm looking for some sort of Bayesian modeling scenario resulting in a multi-modal posterior that I can then try to use as my target distribution.

Thanks a lot for any help. I'm happy to try to provide additional clarification, if necessary.

Comment: If you have no background in this area, or with MCMC at all, my advice is to decline the job, since this is highly advanced material. This is assuming it is a genuine job assignment. If it is an homework of sorts, we cannot help with writing the answer.